# Genexus Error ORA 00942

Tags: java, oracle, genexus, ora-00942

for days I'm experienced this error with `Genexus` (generate with `Java`) using `Oracle` database. I have 2 projects both configured with `Oracle` DB (same settings), one works and the other gives this error:

[image]

> HTTP Status 500 - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

1. I tried everything and reinstall `Oracle` removed reconfiguring the project from scratch. And as usual.
2. I tried to create a new database
3. I tried to do with `Oracle` developer base there and you may write.
4. Restart `Oracle` services.

Any ideas?

PS: This picture shows the connection configuration.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH1mn.jpg)

For some charts I use Gx Reverse Engenieering

Comment: screenshot error here:
http://i185.photobucket.com/albums/x299/condor_bulto/IT/borrar2.png

Comment: Turn on JDBC log to pinpoint the offending SQL sentence. The error is thrown in a prompt. My guess is that the class gx0030_impl is outdated, so i'd check that prompt.

Answer (score 0):

[Rolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV8BK.png)I solved it granted all Rolls to the user involved. Please see image.